# Override window.open()

Tags: javascript, overriding, window.open

I'm trying to override `window.open()`, so I'm trying to find a way to open link in new window without `window.open()`.

In detail, I'm in such a situation: I've got a Silverlight Web Part Which uses `HTMLWindow.Navigate()` to open hyperlinks in new window, so I cannot use `<a>` because I've got totally no control to the Web part. The only way is to override `window.open()`.

For example, when I want to open link in the top window, I override `window.open()` like this:

```
window.open = function (open) {
    return function (url, name, features) {
            window.top.location = url;    
            return false;
       };
    }(window.open);
```

Is there a similar method to open link in new window? Thank you very much!

PS: I cannot use anchor here because I'm overriding `window.open()`

**What I did finally for this problem:**

Firstly, I made a copy of `window.open()`

```
var _open = window.open;
```

Then I override the `window.open()` function. Supposing that "target" is a variable that receives querystring, for example. Note that the default behavior is to open the link in the current window.

```
if (target == "top")
    {
        window.open = function (open) {
            return function (url, name, features) {
                window.top.location = url;
                return false;
           };
        }(window.open);
    }
else if (target == "blank")
{
    window.open = function (open) {
            return function (url, name, features) {
                return open_(url, '_blank', features);
           };
        }(window.open);
}
```

Comment: I think he meant to write 
`return _open(url, '_blank', feature);`
in the else section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From javascript alone you can't open a new window *without* using `window.open()`. Also you have no influence on how the window is opened in new browsers. It depends on the browser-settings whether this opens a new tab or a new window.

You can declare that you want a new window by defining `<a`**[`target="_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)**`href="..."></a>` on a `a`-element, but then the user has to click it. Otherwise if you trigger a click with javascript you will run into the popup blockers of the browsers.

Comment: Thank you @Christoph, I think I could not use `<a>` because I've got no control on the content. Could you tell me more about trigger a click with javascript? And you're sure it would be blocked by popup blocker? Thanks!

Comment: You can call `click()` on the anchor element, but that is potentially considered harmful by the browsers, because this was a common way to spam the user with advertisements.

Comment: You are rigth. I finally made a copy of window.open() before the override, then I used the copied window.open to open the link in new window.