# Override window.open in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open, ieaddon

Is there a way that I can override javascript's window.open in internet explorer on a PC?  I know I can do this on an individual web page, but I want to do this for every web page that a user goes to from this PC.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a set of users who need to keep their toolbars in IE, so I'm trying to figure out how to stop web sites that try to take them away.

Comment: You could conceivably do this from a browser extension, but it would be unreliable and complex. A better approach would be to fix whatever it is that requires the user to have a toolbar present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override window.open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376522/override-window-open)